# Нужна ли запятая перед тире? (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужно ли ставить запятую перед тире в таком предложении:

**"Дата съёмки: 16 мая 2016 – на фотографиях Саладухе 32"**?

Comment: Справедливо только замечание по поводу знака вопроса (я это сейчас исправлю). По поводу слова "год" - несправедливо. "Шестнадцатого мая две тысячи шестнадцатого" - это не ошибка. "Саладухе тридцать два" - это тоже не ошибка.

Comment: Доморощенный знак ii не проходит по-прежнему. При порядковом числительном, записанном арабскими цифрами, должно быть наращение из дефиса и буковок. В «Саладухе 32» недостаёт тире вместо пропущенного «года». Аргумент таков: Мы — в зоне письменной речи.

Comment: ii - это не доморощенный знак, и он встречается в литературе. Означает цифру 2, ведь сайт не позволил мне использовать этот заголовок.

Comment: В "Саладухе 32" можно и не ставить тире. Возможно, писать "2016-го" предпочтительнее, но я не буду, так как "2016" тоже встречается. Я заметил, что Вы очень агрессивный редактор. И навязываете свой стиль изложения. Однако я задал вопрос по поводу запятой и не планирую менять слова. Вы достаточно компетентны, чтобы ответить на него или нет?

Comment: Ищущий компетентного да обрящет.

Comment: Что хотел сказать автор (в более подробном изложении)? Саладуха — фамилия? Что такое  Саладуха 32? Почему Саладуха стоит в дательном падеже: (кому?) Саладухе, а не в родительном (кого?, чьи?)?

Answer (score 0):

Двоеточие мне не кажется верным. Лучне оформить как вставную конструкцию:

***Дата съёмки — 16 мая 2016 – на фотографиях Саладухе 32***.

Хотя эта же конструкция может быть одновременно и **пояснением**, но запятую во всех вариантах **ставить не нужно**.